# How to set custom title in Phalcon Controller

Tags: view, controller, title, phalcon

I was created a main layout , layouts , and controller view .

But how to set custom title product / name in view ?

Main layouts

```
{{ get_doctype() }} 
<html>  
<head>      
    {{ get_title() }}
</head>     
<body>    
    {{ content() }} 
</body> 
</html>
```

Layouts

```
{{ content() }}
```

And Controllers View

```
"Controller View"
```

In IndexController

```
Phalcon\Tag::setTitle("Welcome to my Page");
```

And Nothing return ?
Please help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout the example base controller located in https://github.com/phalcon/invo/blob/master/app/controllers/ControllerBase.php

Later look at how the other controllers use initialize() to define tittle.